# what is correct way to test for xs:decimal in XSL?

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to display different information depending on incoming data.  If it's an integer, I want to display just the number, if it's a decimal, I want to use 0.00# pattern.  Ya, I know, a bit mixed up, but that's the development spec. :>

I have the following XSL for this specific section but I can't see to get past the xsl:when error message of

> "Expected end of expression, found
>   'castable'. number(SAVG) -->castable
>   <-- as xs:decimal"

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="number(SAVG) > 0">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="number(SAVG) castable as xs:decimal">
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(SAVG, '###,###,##0.00#')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(SAVG, '###,###,##0.###')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="number(SAVG) = 0">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;lt;</xsl:text>1
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>N/A</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

I tried looking/poking around for answers and I have tried "instance of", I've tried using xsl:if, etc but I can't seem to get this to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**From comments:**

> Yes, we are using 1.0. I'm sorry I'm
>   new to the XSL processing, how do I
>   glue your XSL and input to generate
>   the html?

Comment: This is XSLT 2.0. If you are running this with XSLT 1.0 processor, please say so.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a short and complete XSLT 2.0 solution.

Comment: I have added an XSLT 1.0 solution to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I. XSLT 1.0**:

There are no xs:integer and xs:decimal in the XPath 1.0 data model used by XSLT 1.0.

**Here is a code snippet that you may use**:

```
    <xsl:choose> 
        <xsl:when test="not(floor(SAVG) = SAVG)"> 
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(SAVG, '###,###,##0.00#')"/> 
        </xsl:when> 
        <xsl:otherwise> <!-- Integer value -->
            <xsl:value-of select="SAVG"/> 
        </xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose>
```

**Do note**: To test if a numeric value is an integer, we use the following test:

```
 floor($someNum) = $someNum
```

---

**Here is one way to do this:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select=
   "for $num in (3, 3.14)
     return
       if($num instance of xs:integer)
         then ($num, ' is xs:integer', '&#xA;')
         else if($num instance of xs:decimal)
           then ($num, ' is xs:decimal', '&#xA;')
           else ($num, ' is something else', '&#xA;')
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
3  is xs:integer 
3.14  is xs:decimal
```

**Or, using the `format-number()` function as per your example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select=
   "for $num in (3, 3.14)
     return
       if($num instance of xs:integer)
         then (format-number($num, '###,###,##0.###'), '&#xA;')
         else if($num instance of xs:decimal)
           then (format-number($num, '###,###,##0.00#'), '&#xA;')
           else ()
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces**:

```
3 
3.14
```

Comment: @Dimitre: +1 I like this XSLT 2.0 more.

Comment: @Dimitre: OP comments that he/she needs XSLT 1.0, now

Comment: @Alejandro: I added also an XSLT 1.0 solution.

Comment: @Dimitre: I will +1 if I could for `fn:floor` numeric test.

Comment: OH MAN!  Taking the floor of the value to test for integer/decimal?  That's cool, and I thought of it too, just didn't take it to the next logical step and try it.  DOH!  Thank you very much guys!  Awesome and it works like a charm!!!!!

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I know this thread is not active now but checking floor would fail for values like 100.00?This would return true even though it is has decimals.

Comment: @themanwhosoldtheworld: Why do you think 100.00 is not an integer? It *is*. Any integer is a decimal, whose fractional part is 0.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I guess my requirement was a little different, I was looking for a way to identify decimals with digits after decimal separator so I tried to use the floor check, but it would fail for 100.00 which I wanted to identify as a decimal.

Comment: @themanwhosoldtheworld, If you can use XSLT 2.0 (XPath 2.0), in your case: `100.00 instance of xs:integer` evaluates to `false()` and this is exactly what you need. The classic math definition of integer can be obtained using: `100.00 castable as xs:integer` -- this evaluates to `true()` . Anyway, the real type of numbers in XPath 1.0 is always `double` -- there is no `xs:decimal` or `xs:integer` types in XPath 1.0. This means that any such expression only helps us decide whether or not a given double value happens to be the value of an integer or not.

Comment: @themanwhosoldtheworld, In case you must use XPath 1.0, just use: `not(contains($yourNum, '.'))`

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I use XPath 2.0 , i first tried this but it failed with error which says something like the variable is not of type string , it is numeric.

Comment: @themanwhosoldtheworld, Then the best expression to use for your problem really is: `100.00 instance of xs:integer`  and it evaluates to `false()` as you want.

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT 1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="test">
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- Not number or number less than zero -->
            <xsl:when test="0 > SVGA or number(SVGA) != SVGA">
                <xsl:text>N/A</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- Number zero -->
            <xsl:when test="SVGA = 0">
                <xsl:text>&lt;1</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- Integer number -->
            <xsl:when test="floor(SVGA) = SVGA">
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(SVGA,'###,###,##0.###')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- Double number -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(SVGA,'###,###,##0.00#')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<root>
    <test>
        <SVGA>0</SVGA>
    </test>
    <test>
        <SVGA>12131</SVGA>
    </test>
    <test>
        <SVGA>123.5654</SVGA>
    </test>
    <test>
        <SVGA>-12.1</SVGA>
    </test>
    <test>
        <SVGA>-7528</SVGA>
    </test>
    <test>
        <SVGA>zero</SVGA>
    </test>
</root>
```

Output:

```
&lt;1
12,131
123.565
N/A
N/A
N/A
```

**Edit 3**: Better test order (plus Dimitre's expression), better test case, closer input sample to questioner.

Comment: Yes, we are using 1.0.  I'm sorry I'm new to the XSL processing, how do I glue your XSL and input to generate the html?

Comment: @PHenry: See my edit for XSLT 1.0 solution. I don't understand what you mean by `glue (...) to generate the html`. Please, post input sample and desired output.

Comment: re glue, oh sorry, I meant what do I need to do with those lines?  I figured the XSL goes into an XSL file, and the html part goes into an html file, but I'm not sure how to reference the xsl from the html.  if this is completely wacked, I apologize, I'm trying to learn as I go here.

Comment: @PHenry: I think that you already have runned a transformation before... You should replace your `xsl:choose` instruction with the one's Dimitre or I have posted (replacing when proper, i.e. `.` with `SAVG` in mine)