# XSL checking integer

Tags: xslt

How to check the integer value in XSL? I'm using version 1.0

This is what I've tried, but it's not working:

```
<xsl:variable name="ShowEmailEventId"
     select="com.zoniac.emailevent.NewEmailEventBean/emailEventIdString"/>
<xsl:if test="$ShowEmailEventId !=48">
    <table align="center"
           width="96%"
           border="1"
           style="border-color:#2E73AD;border-collapse:collapse"
           cellspacing="0"
           cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <td width="10%"
                style="border-color:#2E73AD;color: black; font: 11px verdana;padding:2px"
                align="left"
                valign="top">
                <b>S.No</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: To elaborate, what kind of input are you looking at, and what do you want to know about it?

Comment: I have to get two integer values .If the values comes,then it will accept one condition otherwise it's not.

Comment: Almost duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824653/what-is-correct-way-to-test-for-xsdecimal-in-xsl

Comment: no it's not duplicate..It's two different integer values.

Comment: @AdalArasan: Then, please, elaborate more your question.

Comment: @Adal: I don't understand "if the value comes".

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the shortest possible XPath expression to use in verifying if a value can be used (is) an integer. :)

Comment: @AdalArasan: Do you want to test if `$ShowEmailEventId` is an integer then if not equal to 48?

Comment: Yes .If the values not equal to 48 ,the table comes otherwise not

Answer (score 5):

**This is probably the shortest expression**, returning `true()` iff $x can be used as an integer:

**Just use**:

```
floor($x) = $x
```

**The full test will be**:

```
<xsl:if test="floor($x) = $x">
 <!-- $x is an integer -->
</xsl:if>
```

or

```
<xsl:when test="floor($x) = $x">
 <!-- $x is an integer -->
</xsl:when>
```

or

```
someXPathExpression[floor($x) = $x]
```

Comment: Is this floor() method is used in XSL 1.0 ?

Comment: @AdalArasan : Yes, this is a standard XPath 1.0 function and XSLT 1.0 uses XPath 1.0. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-floor

Answer (score 3):

TO check if a value `nameofint` is an int... (you are obviously going to want to change the inside of the if condition.

```
<xsl:template match="CheckInt">
   <xsl:if test="not(string(.) castable as xs:integer)">
    <xsl:text>NOT AN INT: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: So?  I don't see a version specified?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 doesn't have "castable as".