# Xpath test if is numeric OR valid numeric expression

Tags: xslt, xpath

It is quite simple to find out if a node value is numeric by for example:

```
<xsl:if test="string(number(myNode)) != 'NaN'">
   <!-- myNode is numeric -->
</xsl:if>
```

But, what if myNode contains a fraction or other valid numeric expression? What is the best way to find that out?

Example XML:

```
<data id="1">34</data>
<data id="2">52.3</data>
<data id="3">5/9</data>
<data id="4">10*20</data>
<data id="5">foo</data>
```

Example XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//data">
   <xsl:if test="string(number(.)) != 'NaN'">
      <isNumeric><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></isNumeric>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
```

Will generate the output:

```
<isNumeric>1</isNumeric>
<isNumeric>2</isNumeric>
```

But what is the easiest way to write the xpath expression (or xsl code) to generate the following output:

```
<isNumeric>1</isNumeric>
<isNumeric>2</isNumeric>
<isNumeric>3</isNumeric>
<isNumeric>4</isNumeric>
```

...since data id 3 and 4 also are valid numeric expressions.

It is ok to assume the node value does not contain any spaces as this is controlled by the schema used.

Comment: You would need to use dynamic XPath evaluation which is only provided by certain XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 processors as an extension or by processors implementing the XSLT 3.0 draft. So tell us which XSLT processor you use or check whether it supports http://exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html or similar. Another option would be to implement parsing and evaluation of your numeric expressions in XSLT but at least in XSLT 1.0 that would be quite tedious.

Comment: I am unfortunately stuck with XSLT 1.0 (not my choice). The real problem is actually that I need to know wether the value is an integer or decimal point value. Maybe that opens up for another solution? (i.e. 5/9 is not an integer value, but 4/2 is. 34.4 is not an integer value but 34.0 is (even though it contains a decimal point))

Comment: As you even cannot use regular expressions, you're stuck with using `translate` to remove all non-digit and "math operator" characters. If anything remains, output is invalid. But this allows input like `///` or `1.2.3`, of course.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015741/xsl-checking-integer how to check if a numeric value is an integer. But that will work if you have a numeric value, not if you need to evaluate an numeric expression.

Comment: In XSLT 1.0 context, almost any API provides mechanisms for extension functions registration. Thus, you could also use the hosting language for dynamic evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need to validate your expressions so `4/0` or even `4/+/9` are OK then

```
<xsl:if test="translate(.,'0123456789.+-/* ','')=''">
   <isNumeric><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></isNumeric>
</xsl:if>
```